# `chown postgres` of a subdirectory not working for a new disk

Tags: permissions, mount, users, postgresql, chown

To give postgres more space, I mounted a ssd at:
/mnt/fast_data/

What I'd like to accomplish is to give the postgres user ownership to the postgresql directory, so it doesn't say permission denied.

```
$ sudo chown -R root:root /mnt/fast_data/
$ sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /mnt/fast_data/postgresql/
```

When I test with:

```
su postgres

postgres@my_machine:  cd /mnt/fast_data/postgresql
```

I get the error=>>

```
bash: cd: /mnt/fast_data/postgresql: Permission denied
```

It does work when I `chown -R postgres:postgres /mnt/fast_data` giving ownership over the entire new drive. But surely there's a way to to only give access to the sub-directory. postgres has ownership over `var/lib/postgres` even though `var/lib` is owned by root. Am I missing something in regards to additional drives?

*Additional requested info:*

```
$ sudo ls -ld /mnt/fast_data /mnt/fast_data/postgresql
drwxrwx--- 3 main_user main_user 4096 Jul 22 00:18 /mnt/fast_data
drwxr-xr-x 6 postgres  postgres  4096 Jul 18 22:07 /mnt/fast_data/postgresql
```

```
$ mount | grep /mnt/fast_data
/dev/nvme0n1 on /mnt/fast_data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show)
```

Comment: What file system is `/mnt/fast_data` and how is it mounted? Please add to your question the output of `ls -ld /mnt/fast_data /mnt/fast_data/postgresql` and `mount | grep /mnt/fast_data`, to check that permissions are set correctly.

Comment: @zwets I added this ^^ info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The permissions on the `/mnt/fast_data` directory are `drwxrwx---`, meaning that user `main_user` and group `main_user` have full access (read, write, access), but all others have no permissions at all.

You need to `chmod o+rx /mnt/fast_data` so that its permissions become `drwxrwxr-x`, giving others the permission to see its contents and access it.